# Why View dispatchKeyEvent method not called?

Tags: android, keyevent

My activity would show a ShowcaseView which add to decor view`((ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(mShowcaseView);`
,and i wanna detect the key event to handle something,so i override the `dispatchKeyEvent()` to do what i desired. but it seem like `dispatchKeyEvent()` method never get called,whats worse, `PhoneWindow.DecorView#dispatchKeyEvent()` neither get called,i don't know why,please help me.

Thanks.:)

here is my `ShowcaseView` briefly source code.

```
public class ShowcaseView extends FrameLayout {
    public ShowcaseView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ShowcaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init(context);
    }

    public ShowcaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        setFocusable(true);
        setEnabled(true);
    }

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d("Showcase", "dispatchKeyEvent: called");
    super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    return executeKeyEvent(event);
}

private boolean executeKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
            && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
        hide();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Nobody? This shouldn't be difficult to answer for people that know the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html:

*Note: When handling keyboard events with the KeyEvent class and related APIs, you should expect that such keyboard events come only from a hardware keyboard. You should never rely on receiving key events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard).*

To dispatch key events from on-screen keyboard you can add textWatcher to editText.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

But i cannot see input fields in your code snippet.